# How to find the index of first occurence of any character from another string in a string?

Tags: java

```
/* returns the index of the first occurrence of any of the
 * characters in chars in String s or -1 if none of the characters
 * in chars are found in s. */
```

Above are the instructions, below is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     indexOfAny("kabomba","bomb");

}   

public static int indexOfAny(String s, String chars) {

        int index = 0;
        String rev = "";

        for(int i = s.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            rev+=s.charAt(i);
        }

        String x = rev;

        for(int i = 0;i<x.length();i++){

            for(int j = 0; j<chars.length();j++){
                if(x.charAt(i)==chars.charAt(j)){
                    index = i;//**
                }else {
                    index = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(index);
        return index;
    }
```

To rephrase, the problem is at ** where the it will reach string x last character and compare if the characters in chars string are same and return -1, but I want the code to end and return the index of string x at the i after the last occurrence of any of characters from string chars in string x.

so the output should be 4. because the index of b, which is one of characters of string chars, in the reverse string is 4, which is what I want.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free homework service, despite what you may have heard or been told.  _You_ need to tell us where the problem is in your code, or at least your best estimate as to the problem.

Comment: I imagine you want to break out the loop when you find a match, so after `index = i;` add `break;`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringUtils class which prevents to iterate the loop.
[Here are the indexOf methods present.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqUTd.png)
                     OR

[You can use String.indexOf method which is present under string class.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZR2H.png)

Comment: Yes, my mistake it is indexOf.
Under StringUtils class there are more methods of indexOf as we can get the position of multiple characters at once.

Comment: The [edit link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46881287/edit).

Answer (score -1):

[IndexOf is already available as part of std java.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))